# Setting a texture in ThreeJS does nothing

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to set a texture to an already existing mesh like this:

```
const texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

(The source a HTML5 canvas and that part works ok.)

```
...

mesh.material[0].map = texture;
```

I can change the material color without any problems, but setting the texture doesn't change anything. I guess this is not how changing the texture should be done..? I'm using MeshPhongMaterial.

So, long story short: I want to be able dynamically change a texture of an mesh.

Edit:

I'm trying to set the texture to one of the materials of a Collada model that is loaded. By using dev tools I can see that the texture is there in the object, but it is just not visible. I can change the color of the same material without any problems. Sometimes I can see the texture appearing with wrong colors after a very long idle time (which is weird).

Comment: the code does not give enough context to see what the problem would be but this fiddle should help: http://bl.ocks.org/MAKIO135/eab7b74e85ed2be48eeb

Comment: Where is `canvas` coming from? What you're doing seems to work fine with textures loaded from `TextureLoader`...

Comment: just in case, there is [`THREE.CanvasTexture()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/textures/CanvasTexture).

Comment: I'm trying to set the texture to one of the materials of a Collada model that is loaded. By using dev tools I can see that the texture is there in the object, but it is just not visible. I can change the color of the same material without any problems. Sometimes I can see the texture appearing with wrong colors after a very long idle time (which is weird).

Comment: there is a three.js example that will probably help you. https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_texture_canvas

Comment: Yes, the problem is that despite doing exactly like in the examples the texture is not appearing. I've been debugging this for hours so I have googled and seen all examples. I was hoping that someone could guess a possible reason for this behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is some Collada-specific thing, but it seems that the whole material needs to be replaced. This way I can change the texture.